# Laravel 5.2: How to test helper function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel. I have read the laravel documentation on testing but I do not seem to understand it. Could someone guide me on the steps to test this helper function?

Below is the function.

```
function getUnreadInboxMessagesForAUserById($id)
{

    $past_period_months = Carbon::now()->subMonths(6);

    $message = App\Message::select("*")
    ->whereIn("conversation_id", App\Conversation::select("id")
    ->where([
        ["user_one", "=", $id],
        ["delete_user_one", "=", 0]
    ])
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where("created_at", ">", $user_one_convo_deleted_at)->orWhereNull("user_one_convo_deleted_at");
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where("created_at", ">", $user_one_msgs_deleted_at)->orWhereNull("user_one_msgs_deleted_at");
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where([
        ["user_two", "=", $id],
        ["delete_user_two", "=", 0]
        ])
        ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where("created_at", ">", $user_two_convo_deleted_at)->orWhereNull("user_two_convo_deleted_at");
        })
        ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where("created_at", ">", $user_two_msgs_deleted_at)->orWhereNull("user_two_msgs_deleted_at");
        });
    })
    )
    ->where([
    ["is_seen", "=", 0],
    ["user_id", "<>", $id]
    ])
    ->whereNotIn("user_id", App\DeactivateAccount::select("user_id"))
    ->where(function($query) {
    $query->whereNotIn("user_id", App\User::select("id")
        ->where([
        ["flag", "=", 0],
        ["id", "=", $user_id]
        ])
        ->orWhereIn("user_id", App\User::select("id")
            ->where("id", "=", $user_id)
            ->whereIn("membership", ["admin","premium","free-premium","diamond"]))
        );
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
    $query->where("hard_delete", "=", 0)->orWhereNull("hard_delete");
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
    $query->where("deleted_from_receiver", "=", 0)->orWhereNull("deleted_from_receiver");
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
    $query->where("isflaged", "!=", 1)->orWhereNull("isflaged");
    })
    ->where("created_at", ">=", $past_period_months)
    ->orderBy("created_at", "desc")
    ->get()
    ->count();

    return $messages[0];
}
```

It would be really helpful if you could list the steps in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel thinker :

```
php artisan thinker
```

Then run your class of function [tutorial](https://beyondco.de/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-php-artisan-tinker#:%7E:text=The%20command%20is%20built%20into,the%20output%20to%20the%20console.)

Answer (score 0):

Create seprate folder for Helper functions inside app folder, suppose the helper file name is `common.php` the path will be `app/Helpers/Common.php`

you can either create a Service provider and load the file inside that provider and import it inside providers in config/app.php
or you can try autoloading using composer

if you want to use service providers

Create a helper service provider class : `app/Providers/HelperServiceProvider.php` and use the code mentioned below

```
<?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Register the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {   
            /**
             * Path to the helper file
             */
            require_once __DIR__ . '/../Helpers/Common.php';
        }
    }
```

If you want to use composer autoload open composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Common.php" // <---- ADD THIS PATH TO THE HELPER FILE
    ]
},
```

Once updated the composer.json run `composer dump-autoload`.

I personally recommend to use the Service Provider.

Once you imported everything correctly you can us `getUnreadInboxMessagesForAUserById($id)` function anywhere in the project.